# Could not connect Spring MVC application to AmazonMQ Broker

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, activemq-classic, amazon-mq

I have a spring MVC application in which I want to integrate ActiveMQ, I have successfully connected it to  local ActiveMQ broker but when i put credentials of AmazonMQ into it,it gives the following error

```
Could not connect to broker URL: "brokerurl". Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:374)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:244)
at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:288)
at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:97)
at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:94)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1012)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.addObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1192)
at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:226)
... 54 more

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:285)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.connect(TcpTransport.java:525)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doStart(TcpTransport.java:488)
at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:55)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.start(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:169)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.start(InactivityMonitor.java:52)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.start(WireFormatNegotiator.java:72)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:354)
... 62 more
```

Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>myapp</name>



<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<!-- <properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>public</id>
        <url>http://maven.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories> -->

<dependencies>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>


  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Apache ActiveMQ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache QPid -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-jms-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.29.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring JmsTemplate -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>




<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--    RabbitMQ Starter Dependency (Not required if you're using the simple in-memory broker for STOMP)
 -->    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Connection Pooling -->



    <!-- Following dependency is required for Full Featured STOMP Broker Relay -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.53</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version><!-- $NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2-b02</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version> 
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version> 
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
        <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.53.0</version><!-- 
        <version>7.24.0</version> -->
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.4.8.Final</version>   
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version> 
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java


    Required for notification -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

  <!--   Stage   -->  
  <version>5.1.6</version> 
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20141113</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
      <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
      <version>6.8.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>       


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
        <artifactId>http2-http-client-transport</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.alpn</groupId>
        <artifactId>alpn-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.v20160715</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fernandospr</groupId>
        <artifactId>javapns-jdk16</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Pushy for iOS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.turo</groupId>
        <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Manage connection pool with c3po -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>





    <!-- <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build> -->
```

Following is the code of connection and sending the msg

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("broker-url");
        // Pass the username and password.
        connectionFactory.setUserName("admin");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("password");
        PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory();
        pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        Connection producerConnection = pooledConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        producerConnection.start();
        Session producerSession = producerConnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination producerDestination = producerSession.createQueue(queueName);
        MessageProducer producer = producerSession.createProducer(producerDestination);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
        ObjectMessage producerMessage = producerSession.createObjectMessage(chatMessages);
        producer.send(producerMessage);
        producer.close();
        producerSession.close();
        producerConnection.close();
```

The wierd thing is that when i created a sample spring boot project to test the scenario surprisingly it works perfectly fine and connected to the remote broker without any error. That sample project also worked well for ActiveMQ local instance.I have cross checked to ensure that the actual project has all dependencies,also tried changing version of spring boot in my actual project and matched it with the sample project spring boot version but no luck.
Following I am also attaching sample project code

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.activemq</groupId>
<artifactId>application</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>application</name>
<description>Demo project for Activemq</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

     <!-- Apache Connection Pooling -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Apache ActiveMQ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache QPid -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-jms-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.29.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring JmsTemplate -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

main class for creating connection and sending msgs

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {



private static void
sendMessage(PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory) throws JMSException {
    // Establish a connection for the producer.
    final Connection producerConnection = pooledConnectionFactory
            .createConnection();
    producerConnection.start();

    // Create a session.
    final Session producerSession = producerConnection
            .createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    // Create a queue named "MyQueue".
    final Destination producerDestination = producerSession
            .createQueue("MyQueue1");

    // Create a producer from the session to the queue.
    final MessageProducer producer = producerSession
            .createProducer(producerDestination);
    producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

    // Create a message.
    final String text = "Hello from Amazon MQ!";
    final TextMessage producerMessage = producerSession
            .createTextMessage(text);

    // Send the message.
    producer.send(producerMessage);
    System.out.println("Message sent.");

    // Clean up the producer.
    producer.close();
    producerSession.close();
    producerConnection.close();
}

private static PooledConnectionFactory
createPooledConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    // Create a pooled connection factory.
    final PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory =
            new PooledConnectionFactory();
    pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(10);
    return pooledConnectionFactory;
}

private static ActiveMQConnectionFactory createActiveMQConnectionFactory() {
    // Create a connection factory.
    final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(WIRE_LEVEL_ENDPOINT);
   connectionFactory.setUserName(ACTIVE_MQ_USERNAME);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(ACTIVE_MQ_PASSWORD);
    return connectionFactory;
}

private static final int DELIVERY_MODE = DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT;
private static final int ACKNOWLEDGE_MODE = Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE;






    // Specify the connection parameters.
    private final static String WIRE_LEVEL_ENDPOINT 
            = "broker-url";
private final static String ACTIVE_MQ_USERNAME = "admin";
private final static String ACTIVE_MQ_PASSWORD = "password";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                createActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        final PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory =
                createPooledConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        sendMessage(pooledConnectionFactory);
        pooledConnectionFactory.stop();

}
    }
```

Please bear in mind that sample project works well for both local and remote message broker while my actual project works well with local broker but not with remote AmazonMQ Broker

Answer (score 0):

From the logs that you posted, it seems like `Could not connect to broker URL: "brokerurl".` where `brokerurl` isn't a valid endpoint. Make sure your endpoint actually is a valid endpoint.